# What are the disadvantages of using undeclared maven dependencies (through transitive dependencies)?

Tags: maven

Maven includes transitive dependencies in a project class path to eliminate the need to redefine these dependencies over and over again each time a module depends on a third party module.
The version of transitive dependencies used can be controlled from a dependency management section in the root pom. So it is controllable.

So why using transitive dependencies in a project without explicitly declaring it in its pom file is considered a bad practice ?

Comment: Simple answer yes...see also the answer of JFMeier...

Answer (score 3):

Usually, you update your dependencies after some time. 
The update can lead to lost transitive dependencies which will then directly affect your program.

If, on the other hand, you write down all dependencies you use explicitly, it is much easier to make updates and see what you really use.

Comment: Updating dependencies is a manual action, if I do it then I typically do a full build/test afterwards. If the build/test fails, then I'll check then what's missing.

Comment: @AhmedHammad I believe he's referring to transitive dependencies which "YOU YOURSELF" use in your app without explicitly declaring them. Suppose you use spring-boot in your app and you know that in turn it uses slf4j. Since slf4j is transitive you can use it "inherited from spring" without explicitly declaring it in your pom. After a while you decide to upgrade the spring version, but in the mean time the spring team decided to no longer use slf4j, case in which your app will no longer compile.

Comment: @AhmedHammad Updating dependencies is not always a manual process this can be automated which requires having good tests...